# How to prevent uninstall of Android application by random user using OTP or any other method?

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android application which need installer permission to get uninstalled using OTP on a provided contact number. If any other person want to uninstall the application he will be asked to enter OTP.

How I can I do this in Andorid ?

Comment: Study a bit,  write some code and then come back here for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Device Administration**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

you need to register your application as a Device Administrator,after that it can't be uninstalled unless its unregistered. This will provide restrictions so that  the app can not be  uninstalled.